Outlines not working as expected in React three fiber?
We are implementing outlines in React three fiber. We've tried 2 approaches and both do not work as expected.
With r3f outlines (example), the outlines simply don't appear. Code:
<mesh>
        <boxGeometry />
        <meshBasicMaterial transparent color={"white"} />

        {/* Selection Outline */}
        <Outlines
          color={"#0577b0"}
          thickness={0.07}
          visible={
            props.hovered ||
            (selectedElement !== null &&
              selectedElement.uuid === props.data.uuid)
          }
          renderOrder={999}
        />
      </mesh>

With Drei (docs and example from drei), yet we are experiencing some problems that are not present in the example, specifically:

Jitter
Offset on flat objects
Only visible from one side and z fighting on other side
Z fighting / glitching when zoomed out



Code:
<effectComposer ref={composer} args={[gl]}>
        <renderPass attach="passes" args={[scene, camera]} />
        <outlinePass
          attach="passes"
          renderToScreen={true}
          args={[aspect, scene, camera]}
          selectedObjects={hovered}
          visibleEdgeColor="white"
          edgeStrength={50}
          edgeThickness={10}
        />
        <shaderPass
          attach="passes"
          args={[FXAAShader]}
          uniforms-resolution-value={[1 / size.width, 1 / size.height]}
        />
      </effectComposer>

Has anyone encountered this before / are there camera or render settings to look for? How can we achieve the outlines displayed in either of the examples?
